# How to implement iphone bluetooth chat?

Tags: iphone, sdk, chat, gamekit

Hello 
I have implemented iphone bluetooth chat by following steps give in tutorial below.
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/1954.
It is working well.But it shows iphone to which connection should be done
in standard interface provided by  gkpeerpickercontroller.But i want to display
list of all connected devices in tableview or any other subview.How can 
i do that?Does any tutorial or sample code available for that?

Comment: Search for the project named "Beam It". Sample code is also available.